# Docker build failed with unsupported platform

Tags: docker, npm, build

when I try to build superset docker from source, node install complains with:

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.0.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

Comment: The docker engine is installed in mac laptop

Comment: Can you share your docker file please